How to use Flutter with build_runner?
I'm developing a build_runner plugin that captures const widgets and converts them to images. The process should be triggered by running flutter packages pub run build_runner build to create snapshots. However, I'm encountering issues importing Flutter within the build_runner context. When I try to import Flutter, it results in numerous reference errors.
I'm puzzled because if the command line can't use Flutter, how does flutter test work? It seems there should be a way to execute Flutter from the command line.
My questions are:

Is it possible to use Flutter within a build_runner plugin?
If so, how can I properly import and use Flutter in this context?
Are there any specific considerations or limitations when trying to use Flutter with build_runner?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Using Flutter directly within a build_runner plugin is challenging due to environment limitations. But yes u can, i would suggest u should consider using Dart's reflection
Consider using Dart's reflection to extract widget information .
The main limitations are performance implications, maintainability, and error handling when working with Flutter and build_runner.


Do you know how flutter_test run flutter on command line?

Yes, navigate to your root directory of the flutter project and run flutter test  this will run all the tests in the test directory of your flutter project.  If you want to run only specific test flutter test test/path_to_your_test_file.dartyou can also pass additional options like --verbose (for detailed logs) & --coverage (for coverage information)

I think I can use flutter test command to make a cli tool to generate what I want, thank you.
